# Getting price on call resource object as negative value, Twilio

Tags: twilio, twilio-api

I have subaccounts under my master account when I am fetching all call resources with my master rest client, all call resources have negative 'price' value and when I am adding all these prices its coming out to be (-0.69200 USD)

```
all_calls = client.calls.list()
all_calls_price1 = sum(v.price for v in all_calls if v.price)
```

and comparing it absolute value to price on 'all time' usage record of 'calls' category its coming out to be (2.04 USD); price caclulated with both methods are not equal, I am using Twilio-Python package

```
b=client.usage.records.all_time.list()
all_calls_price2 = [k.price for i,k in enumerate(b) if k.category =='calls'][0]
```

Comment: Hi, this is not really a Stack Overflow question as there's nothing wrong with your code. I would get in touch with [Twilio help](https://www.twilio.com/help/contact) and see what they can find out about this issue on your account.

Comment: Thanks for getting in touch, @philnash

Comment: For information, did you had any explanation from them @RajdeepSharma?